# How to scrape web site span class problem?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a new bee in programing. I try to exctract some data using `Beautifulsoup` on web site called whatclinic.

Link: https://www.whatclinic.com/dentists/turkey/mugla-province/yalikavak/dt-ufuk-kayhan

On the given web site there some ratings, comments about the clinics which i like to grab. I try so many ways including reading the threads on stackoverflow. But cant manage to do it. Also  i need itearation cause the reviews continues on.

I hope somebody helps. Thank you and sorry for my english.
Below I try to exctract rating stars from the link.

```
!pip install beautifulsoup4
import requests
r= requests.get("https://www.whatclinic.com/dentists/turkey/mugla-province/yalikavak/dt-ufuk-kayhan")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
print(soup.get_text())

results=soup.find_all("span",attrs={"class":"stars-rate"})
len(results)

results.contents
```

Answer (score 0):

*Your code and you should always include these details into your question, will give you:*

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'contents'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

---

So you have to iterate the `ResultSet` to get your goal:

```
for e in soup.find_all("span",attrs={"class":"stars-rate"}):
    print(e.contents)
```

If you like to get the ratingValues instead:

```
soup.find_all("span",attrs={"property":"ratingValue"})
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r= requests.get("https://www.whatclinic.com/dentists/turkey/mugla-province/yalikavak/dt-ufuk-kayhan")

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
for e in soup.find_all("span",attrs={"class":"stars-rate"}):
    print(e.contents)
```

Comment: Thank you but when i run this code i coudnt get the actual ratings instead i get something like this

Comment: <span property="starsRating"> <i class="fa fa-star-yellow fa-star">

Comment: That is exact what the focus of your question deals with - In futur question you should add an expected output - However if you need the ratingValues -> `soup.find_all("span",attrs={"property":"ratingValue"})`

Comment: The code worked for me, but there seems to be another problem. When I run it it only scrapes 12 reviews. But I need 133 reviews. I assume the problem is the "see more reviews" button. The page link does not change when I press this button. Therefore, I think I need a code to click this button. And also maybe a loop migth be useful.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus and detailed information what you expect to get. It also keep this question clean and you will practice [ask]